# onclick return and javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick

and thanks to anyone who can help me!

I have a text with this code:

```
<a onclick="return showPic(this); mostrarespectacular()" href="Imatges/productosnuevos/urbano01.jpg">&nbsp Circuito Espectacular Barcelona</a>
```

and the scripts are:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showPic (whichpic) {
 if (document.getElementById) {
  document.getElementById('imgContenedor').src = whichpic.href;
  if (whichpic.title) {
      document.getElementById('imgDescripcion').childNodes[0].innerHTML = whichpic.innerHTML;
  }
  return false;
 } else {
  return true;
 }
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function mostrarespectacular() {
    div = document.getElementById('circuloespectacular');
    div.style.display = 'inline';
}
function cerrarespectacular() {
    div = document.getElementById('circuloespectacular');
    div.style.display='none';
}
</script>
```

and my problem is that the first function works perfect but not the second one (which has to show a div). Any ideas of what i'm doing wrong? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "return" is branching out of the script after calling the showPic() function. Remove the return or place it before the "mostrarespectacular()" call or move it to the end, etc.

Comment: @Adam had the same conclusion. I just didn't see that response until I  had posted mine. : )  Glad you got it working anyway!

Answer (score 2):

You **return** from the onclick after the first function call. Remove that and you should be fine.

Comment: mmmm no, if I delete "return" the image i need to see in a div, opens in the same page! I solved the problem just changing the order of the functions!!!!